# iMacros - FRAME NAME="" Issue

Tags: macros, imacros, mailinator

I have recently been using iMacros in an attempt to create a Macro that will navigate to a  mailbox I have created on the website "Mailinator" (http://mailinator.com/), and open a link within a particular email by clicking on it. This was created by recording myself carrying out this process, which was a success. **But when I play the macro, the macro does not click on the link and instead freezes at the line**:

```
FRAME NAME="rendermail
```

This is the code for my macro:

```
VERSION BUILD=8920312 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:inboxfield CONTENT=remorsefive@mailinator.com
enter code here
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BTN ATTR=TXT:Check<SP>it
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:nathan<SP>hemel-stickler
FRAME NAME="rendermail"
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:https://www.link.com/pages/default.aspx/
TAB T=2
```

I have been attempting to use this macro with the plug-in version of iMacros for Firefox. The specs of these are:

- Firefox Version 37.0.1
- iMacros for Firefox 8.9.2

I am using Mac OS X 10.8.5

Here is a link to the mailinator inbox which contains the email with the link that needs to be opened by the macro: http://mailinator.com/inbox.jsp?to=remorsefive#/#maildirpane

I have tried a couple of different workarounds to this issue but have not found a solution yet. Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks